# ABP 401 response from API instead of redirect

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-core-identity

I have the same problem as this: https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=4865, but I have ABP v2.1 with module-zero-core-template.

I'm using **Web.Mvc** project as my startup project and I want to make API calls.

When I perform an unauthorized request to the API, I got a "200 OK" response instead of a "401". Where did I make a mistake?

[image]

Comment: I suppose this is same with https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2321

Comment: Hi, thanks, sorry I missed this issue, yes it is probably the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ASP.NET Core 1.x

ABP v2.x / module-zero-core-template v2.x

Modify [`IdentityRegistrar`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/99798a82fdf602cbfcaff525dabee1410e6cec16/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Core/Identity/IdentityRegistrar.cs#L16) in **.Core** project:

```cs
// Before
services.AddAbpIdentity<Tenant, User, Role>()

// After
services.AddAbpIdentity<Tenant, User, Role>(options =>
{
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = false;
})
```

Reference: [https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/804](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/804#issuecomment-241601121)

## ASP.NET Core 2.0

ABP v3.x / module-zero-core-template v3.0.0 – v3.4.0

Modify [`AuthConfigurer`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/63f6e3b6147b6df7a08b09a53dad562c57dac17c/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Host/Startup/AuthConfigurer.cs#L19) in **.Web.Mvc** / **.Web.Host** project:

```cs
// Before
services.AddAuthentication()

// After
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "JwtBearer";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "JwtBearer";
})
```

Reference: [`92b6270`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/commit/92b6270ab23af4c5e7655c5f111fb8838eb0c09b) in module-zero-core-template v3.5.0

Answer (score 1):

Add this header to your API requests "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" if you want to get a 401 and not a redirect.