# How to redirect to login page in ABP?

Tags: authentication, redirect, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-boilerplate

1. I download the .NET Core sample from ASP.NET Boilerplate website,
2. change the DB connection string, update DB,
3. run Web Api, show the Swagger successfully,
4. add a Home/Index View, change Home/Index action to return the View, not Swagger,
5. run again, show home page successfully,
6. then add a Home.Account Controller and Home.Account View, login page.
7. Add `AbpMvcAuthentication` attribute on Home/Index, what I want is when access Home, redirect to login page.

When I go to the Home, it shows an empty page, not Home, nor login page. It seems authenticate failed, but did not redirect to login page.

My question is: how to let `AbpMvcAuthentication` know which page to redirect when authenticate failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no login page for the [***.Web.Host**](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/tree/82a1da929270c2317fc9364da771313eea24ac9f/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Host) project, where the [redirect to Swagger](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/82a1da929270c2317fc9364da771313eea24ac9f/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Host/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L22) is.

You should change your Startup Project to ***.Web.Mvc** instead:

[image]

If you just want to login, consider using [Swagger authentication helpers](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/pull/87#issuecomment-316750655) from the browser console:

```js
abp.swagger.login();
```

---

To answer your question, you can re-enable authentication redirect by reverting commit [`92b6270`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/commit/92b6270ab23af4c5e7655c5f111fb8838eb0c09b):

```cs
// What it was (and what you want)
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>

// What it is
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "JwtBearer";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "JwtBearer";
}).AddJwtBearer("JwtBearer", options =>
```

**Startup.cs**:

```cs
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseJwtTokenMiddleware(); // Add this back

app.UseAbpRequestLocalization();
```

To be clear, this redirects to a blank page since *there is no login page for the ***.Web.Host** project*.

This is the opposite of the expected behaviour in [ABP 401 response from API instead of redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48969686/8601760).

Also, you can [configure login path for redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47438983/8601760):

> You can configure that in [Startup.cs](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/63f6e3b6147b6df7a08b09a53dad562c57dac17c/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/Startup/Startup.cs#L41-L42):
>
> ```cs
> IdentityRegistrar.Register(services);
> AuthConfigurer.Configure(services, _appConfiguration);
>
> // Add this line:
> services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Admin/Login");
> ```
>
> Related docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x